# My UILabel is always nil even even after changing its text. How could I make my UILabel not nil?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var tasks = ["None"]
@IBOutlet weak var taskonelabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func taskbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     tasks.append("Do Your Homework")
     print(tasks)
     if tasks.count > 2{
         taskonelabel?.text = String(tasks[1])
     }
     print(taskonelabel)
```

When running the code, it prints out "tasks" which is `["None", "Do Your Homework"]` and it also print out "taskonelabel" which is nil. I tried to change "taskonelabel.text" to 'Do your Homework' but it stayed as nil. I am a beginner on Swift, so please help me to be able to change "taskonelabel.text" into 'Do Your Homework' when "taskbutton" is pressed.

Comment: Make sure your outlet is properly connected asign text to label in `viewDidLoad` and check whether it is still nil or not?

Comment: You never connected the `taskonelabel` outlet in your storyboard.

Comment: The question mark in `taskonelabel?.text` is nonsense. If the label is not connected it prevents to discover the design error and if the label is properly connected it has no effect anyway.

Comment: How could I connect "taskonelabel" properly? But thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem will be `taskonelabel` not connected properly. If `taskonelabel` connect properly then `Do your Homework` not set on the label. Because `tasks` count is 2 but your condition will true when tasks count greater than 2.

So the solution will be
1. First check outlet connection and
2. Replace the value of condition 2 to 1

Comment: Thank you for the help. But how do I connect "taskonelabel" properly?

Comment: @ThomasTseng you can do it by simply drag and drop. Follow this tutorial you will understand. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2273069&seqNum=4